# SQL and/or functions that retrieves data formatted as XML then transform it to XHTML in PostgreSQL, is it possible?

Tags: sql, xml, postgresql, xhtml, xslt

Is there a way to retrieve the results of an SQL query in XML? If so how? can you provide a short example and/or a link to a good site?

Is it also possible the RDBMS can handle the transformation to XHTML given the XSLT? Would I want to do this anyway? Can I not send a browser XML and the XSLT and it will do the transformation itself?

I am using PostgreSQL 8.4

Comment: The general answer to all this questions is yes: http://durak.org/sean/pubs/software/postgresql/functions-xml.html and http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/interactive/xml2.html

Comment: Did you mean *how*? Alejandro's comment is absolutely correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. Here: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/interactive/functions-xml.html, here: http://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/XML_Support and here: http://www.stylusstudio.com/sqlxml_tutorial.html.

It can using this: xslt_process(). Older browsers will not handle transforming with XSLT and IE as always does something differently but on the other hand you can offload the processing to the client.

Answer (score -1):

Here its explained very well:

http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2009/02/12/sql-server-simple-example-of-creating-xml-file-using-t-sql/

Comment: but thats specific to SQL Server